# Twostep cluster analysis and autoclustering statistics

Tags: clustering, spss

In older versions of SPSS there was displayed an auto-clustering statistics table with e.g. BIC criterion and its change for various cluster solutions. In later versions of SPSS (e.g. 21) I do not see such an output anymore. Is it still available somewhere in later versions and where can it be found?

Comment: Paste the generated command syntax into syntax window. It must contain subcommand `/NUMCLUSTERS AUTO 15 BIC`. If it does but the table "Auto-clustering" is still missing then it is a bug of version 21. I can insure you that you can get the table in versions 20 and 22.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, I cannot find anywhere such a table in my v21, although I see in syntax that subcommand. Then probably its a bug..

Comment: This is not a bug.  You have a choice of Model Viewer output or traditional pivot tables.  Check the "Pivot tables" box on the Output subdialog, and you will get the Auto-Clustering table with this information.